# need help with making seo friendly links

Tags: search-engines, url, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Practice for Formatting SEO-Friendly URLs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/good-practice-for-formatting-seo-friendly-urls)

I'm looking into seo-ing my urls and i was wording which of these link structures was better to use:

1) `www.mydomain.com/contact-john-smith/index.html`
-or-

2) `www.mydomain.com/contact-john-smith/contact.html`
-or-

3) `www.mydomain.com/contact-john-smith.html`

I realize they're all basically the same but i was wondering if any of those permutations had an advantage over the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
www.mydomain.com/contact-john-smith
```

But if you have to use one of three choices then #3 is the closest match to my answer

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning, and why dropping the file name and extension is preferred

Comment: Because `.html` is pretty meaningless. All web pages output HTML, and using the extension doesn't guarantee a static file on the server (it could still be generated with PHP etc).

Answer (score 0):

I would go for option #3.

**Please keep in mind that:**

- It's good to have keyword rich URLs (that helps with linkbuilding and is good for the understanding of the website structure);
- It's important to keep pages you want to rank with close to the root.